# How to continue adding data to the second page of a PDF in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-graphics

I am trying to create a PDF file programmatically in Objective-C and as my data keeps getting larger and larger I need to continue drawing it on the second page. By using the next code I am able to create the necessary number of pages but the content is drawed only on the first one. Any suggestions on what should I change?

```
+(void)drawPDF:(NSString*)fileName
{
    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileName, CGRectZero, nil);
    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

    int currentPage = 1;

    for (int count = 30; count < 3000;  count = count + 100) {

        //add new PDF page if the content doesn't fits on the curent one
        if (currentPage * 792 < count + 30) {
            currentPage ++;
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        }

        [self drawCellFromStartingPoint:count];
    }

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Comment: @Arc676 not sure I understand you question

Comment: Never mind, the rest of the question wasn't rendering properly.

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483933/create-pdf-with-multiple-pages

Answer (score 0):

```
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(...); 
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(...); // start first page

  UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(...); // start second page

  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414112/create-multi-page-pdf-in-objective-c) for more details.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: As I said the problem is not that I can not add the pages, but that, the data is not switching the pages when it draws.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the I was continuing drawing the data fro the current calculated Y position(count value from the for-loop), so in order for it to work properly I had to reset the Y value on each page, so in the end I adjusted the line:

```
[self drawCellFromStartingPoint:count];
```

to work as:

```
[self drawCellFromStartingPoint:count - ((currentPage - 1) * 792)];
```